# What SQL query will return only distinct values in one column?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MYSQL don’t return duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441127/mysql-dont-return-duplicate-rows)

I know this question has been asked before, but I haven't been able to see any solutions that worked with my situation. A typical SQL statement looks like this:

```
SELECT Hostname,Site,Rack FROM hardwaredb WHERE Hostname LIKE '%$hostval%'
```

$hostval is a powershell variable that gets replaced with a system's name. So if I had a system named OldGlory117, the statement would look like this:

```
SELECT Hostname,Site,Rack FROM hardwaredb WHERE Hostname LIKE '%OldGlory117%'
```

Because of other columns, some rows are duplicated, and there are duplicate hostnames in the database. So the above query might return:

```
OldGlory117    USA    Rack1
OldGlory117    USA    Rack1
OldGlory117    USA    Rack1
```

This is problematic when I'm not looking for the column that causes the duplicates. Is there any way to return only rows that have unique values for hostname? What if I'm not specifying hostname in the WHERE statement? Ex:

```
SELECT Hostname,Site,Rack FROM hardwaredb WHERE Rack LIKE '%Rack1%'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged with both sql server and mysql?

Comment: Why is this tagged with powershell is a better question. This is pure sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible for you to use a GROUP BY?

```
SELECT Hostname,Site,Rack FROM hardwaredb WHERE Rack LIKE '%Rack1%' GROUP BY Hostname
```

Comment: This works, thanks. The only issue now is if I want to return all fields. Ex: "SELECT * from hardwaredb WHERE hostname like '%$hostval%'". Is it possible to use GROUP BY with a statement like this?

Comment: Absolutely! Just change your fields to a * and off you go :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT Hostname,Site,Rack FROM hardwaredb WHERE Rack LIKE '%Rack1%' having count(Hostname)=1 GROUP BY Hostname,Site,Rack
```

EDIT:
having clause will hep you to put conditions on group by clause

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do the job for you:

```
SELECT Hostname,Site,Rack FROM hardwaredb WHERE Hostname LIKE '%$hostval%'
GROUP BY Hostname, Site, Rack
```

You can also experiment with the `SELECT DISTINCT` keyphrase, though it might produce unexpected results if you've not used it before...

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you can achieve what you are after using DISTINCT (works as long as all three columns are distinct which they are in the sample data).

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Hostname,Site,Rack 
FROM    hardwaredb 
WHERE   Rack LIKE '%Rack1%'
```

If the values are varying in Site and Rack then you could just use:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Hostname
FROM    hardwaredb 
WHERE   Rack LIKE '%Rack1%'
```

Finally, if you the values are varying in Site and Rack, but you need values for each of these columns you can use (The Order by is important otherwise the query becomes nondeterministic and could yield different results when querying the same data):

```
SELECT  HostName, Site, Rack
FROM    hardwaredb 
WHERE   Rack LIKE '%Rack1%'
GROUP BY HostName
ORDER BY Rack, Site;
```

However, I personally dislike this solution, it would not work in most DBMS, and breaks the ANSI Standard of including columns in the select list that are not dependant on items in the group by. Without understanding your exact requirements though it is diffucult to post an alternative.